# Android picking images and styles from different resouce folders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-drawable, android-screen-support

I am developing an android application targetting for tablet devices as well as mobile devices
For that I have created my layout files like below

For Placing Screens:

```
res
layout-small
layout-large
```

For placing images to fit tablets and mobile devices:

```
res
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
```

For Placing Styles and String xml files:

```
res
values-small(strings.xml and styles.xml)
values-large(string.xml and styles.xml)
```

are there any extra folders need to create my application to work for tablet screens as well as mobile screens ?

but when i run the application in nexus7 emulator and nexus one emulator i'm not able to pick properimages and styles from respective xml files

could any one  help?

Answer (score 1):

change your layout-large and layout-small folder to

layout-sw720dp to support 10"+ tablets
layout-sw600dp will support 7" tablet.

Most of the Tablets will take image from mdpi folder

Answer (score 1):

It is a complicated question and it depends on your desing and layouts.

In general there are more qualifiers to use.

For density there are also hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. For size - normal, xlarge. For orientation - land, port. And you can combine any of those in one folder. For example res/drawable-mdpi-xlarge or res/layout-hdpi-large and so on. And it all depends on design and how you want to display layout on different screens.

For more information check this docs page http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

if you are testing your application on an emulator, then check the properties of your emulator like which device you have chosen and its DPI and whether if it is hdpi, mdpi
These properties are there when you choose a device while creating a new emulator.

You cannot put same resolution images in all the drawable folders.
Please look into this. you will get a more clear picture.
Visit :- [Support Multiple Screen - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)